# How much explosive power does a missile need to destroy a 100km³ meteorite heading for Earth?

Tags: space, apocalypse, orbital-mechanics, meteor

I just wanted to know how much power does a missile need to destroy a 100 km³ meteorite heading for Earth.

Assume whatever meteorite composition is easiest to destroy, and intercept the meteorite at whatever point in its trajectory to keep Earth safe.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the tour and visit the help center to learn more about the site and how to ask questions here. To help you with your question we need more details. For example: as has already been mentioned you only specified a length, not a volume. Please add more information about your scenario so that we can help you. Have fun!

Comment: What explosives, and what would you count as destroyed? Five parts 20km³ each would still be pretty fatal, for example.

Comment: This very much depends on the kind. Meteorite is what reaches the ground after entry through the atmosphere. Before it could have been a comet (ice) or a meteoroid (rock and metal). But whatever it was hitting its side with a shockwave to change its trajectory would be saver than to blow it up and hope the parts are small enough.

Comment: Welcome to the site Mega.  Your question needs to provide a little more information to be answerable.  Primarily we don't know the composition of your meteorite.  One of the best pieces of advice I can give you being new to the site...when asking questions, be *specific* , make sure there is criteria that allow people to look at your question and know there is a **right** or at least **best** answer.  Also, check out the [help] it has some good info too.

Comment: Also to **CLOSE VOTERS** destroying/attempting to destroy the world is 1000*On-Topic.

Comment: Clarify as much as you can: What do you mean by "destroy", break it into 2 pieces? break it into fine sand? Nothing left but plasma? Would it be ok to merely divert it to miss earth and if so how far away is it? What's it made of? A big lump of iron is harder to blow up than a loose ball of gravel.

Comment: around 100Gt of tnt to evaporate the thing (if average density is 2000kg/m$^3$ and strength around 100MPa), considering it would not penetrate to the core of the asteroid,  I would take 10 times more - should be about enough.

Comment: You really can't destroy it.  Trying to do so would break it into pieces, many of which would still hit Earth.  Your best bet is to deflect it.  The power needed would depend on how long in advance you apply it.  If you have years, probably not much at all.  Kerbal space program or something similar might be able to give you real numbers.

Comment: "Too broad"? People here are being very nit-picky about all the information that they "need." It might be nice to know what the meteor is made of, but most people do not know or care about the possible differences, and a good answer would just figure both the best case and worst case to provide a range. A very, very, very large portion of questions asked on World-Building are not nearly as specific as this question and still enjoy plenty of up-votes and thorough answers.

Comment: @James no one voted off-topic, right? Seems all voted too broad. And seeing how many interpretations of destroyed appear in the comments, that's one of two fitting close reasons. Unclear would be valid as well.

Comment: Wild guess, you should detonate them all within 1 millisecond, and they should end all their internal processes with 1ms accuracy, not sure if they that accurate(no one needs that in real life). The Nice extensive answer about the duration of the nuke explosion, including 1Mt examples - https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-a-nuclear-explosion-take . Another option to blast them one by one with certain intervals(obviously they fly one after another at some distance). The whole situation isn't that super simple.

Comment: I upvoted because I don't think the question deserved the down vote so I expressed my opinion. :) I do agree with its ambiguity but I can not specifically tell the OP how to make it better

Comment: @Mołot: I wasn't one of the votes to close, as I think it's a perfectly valid question.  It's just that (to the best of my knowledge, anyway) the answer is "You can't."

Comment: Note that there are other questions already that cover the topic, generally.  You can learn about *ways* to damage/deflect/modify such bodies, the specific energy to unbind it gravitationally, and other concepts.

Comment: It all depends on the distance. Very far away: A fire cracker will make it miss Earth.  Very close: Can't be done.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya While perfectly understandable this behaviour is frowned upon. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes/253386#253386) for a discussion on SO Meta about canceling out downvotes. The essential part is probably: "You should vote based on the merits of the question or answer that you're voting on. If you vote to "cancel out" other people's opinions, you make a mockery of the whole voting process.". If you think the question is good you should upvote it, if you think it's neither good nor bad you should not vote on it.

Comment: @Secespitus Perhaps I was not clear. Let us say I was 50% should vs 50% should not and was choosing abstain .... then a down vote pushed it to 50.0001% to 49.9999% and the button was pushed. Was the down vote a part of the decision? Yes, was it the only reason? No. This is after all the Q/A section and not the chat room :)

Comment: @Secespitus There are also discussions, both Meta and on SE guideline pages, suggesting you should vote however you feel is appropriate. I think what Enigma did is good. In fact, sometimes I withhold up-vote for similar reasons thinking "That information is neat. Maybe I should drop a +1. Wow it's already at +300! It's not *that* good by any means!" and I withhold that +1. If it's an excellent answer then I'll +1 no matter what it's at, even if it's at +9999, but there are situations where taking the current score into consideration is appropriate. Otherwise there's no point showing the score.

Comment: @Secespitus In fact, if we do not make such considerations, then the scores get out of balance easily enough due to various reasons (ex: old answer is outdated, new answer is better but years younger and can't catch up), which happens often. Then the algorithm for ordering Q's and A's is off-balance, deprecated answers continue to get +1s faster than correct answers, and we have "made a mockery of the whole process," as you put it. That's just another consideration. I don't think it's even necessary. "That question doesn't need another +1," or "That question doesn't deserve -10" are sufficient

Comment: @Aaron I was not the one who said we would "make a mockery of the whole process". I was citing the Meta Post I referred to. Voting is anonymous and you can vote however you want. I won't judge you for voting, especially because there normally is no way to find out who voted how. I just saw Enigmas comment and remembered that Meta Post, so I wanted to show it to him. Personally I agree with the Post that just cancelling out another persons vote is like saying "I have no opinion about this post, but I don't like your opinion." Votes should show the quality of the content

Comment: @Secespitus "Votes should show the quality of the content." That is precisely what I am aiming for if I +1 a Q or A I would normally have not voted on of mediocre quality but is sitting at an undeserved -5 or worse. The acts of "always +1 something good" and "always -1 something not good" was seen as a problem shortly after StackOverflow started, as people very quickly got to negative 100 rep or to +thousands of rep, both undeserved. An innocent Q leaving users at -100 rep drove people away. Sometimes I +1 a new 1rep user's first Q that's at -1 just so they don't feel steamrolled and run away